# Why my code prints an extra new line instead of just the amount that the user inputs?

Tags: c, cs50

```
for (rows = 0; rows <= height; rows++)
    {
        for (spaces = 0; spaces < height - rows; spaces++)
        printf(" ");
        for (hashes = 0; hashes < height - spaces; hashes++)
        printf("#");

        printf("\n");
    }
```

This is my code so far, and the top part is what makes the rows.

I was expecting just the amount of rows that the user inputs (ex: 3 rows or 2 rows).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that `height` is the user input.

So just because `rows` loop goes form 0 to `height`, you'll get `height` + 1 rows.

For example, with `height` equals 2, `rows` will takes the values 0, 1 and 2. Which are 3 different values.